# lxappearance changes not sticking

Tags: 13.04, themes, gtk, xmonad

Just installed 13.04, in xmonad, want to change my gtk theme. Run lxappearance, click on ambiance, everything changes in lxapperance, it all looks good. Hit apply. No change to any other app. Close lxappearance and reopen it -- theme reverted back to Raleigh. >.<

Answer (score 2):

Try a small program called gtk-chtheme from synaptic or software centre, I use this on all desktops to quickly change my gtk theme and font...

Comment: That worked for changing the theme to Ambiance, but it doesn't seem to be able to modify the icon set like lxapperance? Is there a way to do that with some other program or manually?

Comment: Nvm, got it. Just added `gtk-icon-theme-name = "unity-icon-theme"` to my `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.